# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).AddFotoramaVideoEvents is not a function magento 2.3.6

Tags: swatches, color-swatches, category-listing

I am facing this uncaught type error in swatch-renderer.js on listing page in magento 2.3.6

Till now i have tried 2 solutions but no luck:
1: added following lines catalog_category_view.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.info.media" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product media" after="product.info.main">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image.gallery" template="Custom_Product::product/view/gallery.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\ProductVideo\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.video" after="product.info.media.image" template="product/view/gallery.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
```

2: swatch-renderer.js

```
if (isInitial) {
    if ($.isFunction($(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).AddFotoramaVideoEvents)) {
        $(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).AddFotoramaVideoEvents();
    }
}
```

i have been facing this issue for a long time.

[image]

Comment: Have you ever figured this out?